# Custom Induction principle for mutually recursive types

Tags: coq

I am a bit confused trying to define the induction principle for some particular mutually recursive type. Using `Schema` does not really solve my issue, that's why I thought about defining the principle myself (maybe my whole approach using mutually recursive types is not appropriate... that's an option too).

I am using Arthur's [extructure](https://github.com/arthuraa/extructures) library (that's where the `ordType` comes from, it could be something else). So, my type is:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.
Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.


From extructures Require Import ord fmap.

Section R.

Variables Name Vals : ordType.

Inductive ResponseObject : Type :=
  | SingleResponse : Result -> ResponseObject
  | MultipleResponses : Result -> ResponseObject -> ResponseObject
  with Result : Type :=
       | Empty : Result
       | Null : Name -> Result
       | SingleResult : Name -> Vals -> Result
       | ListResult : Name -> seq Vals -> Result
       | NestedResult : Name -> ResponseObject -> Result
       | NestedListResult : Name -> seq ResponseObject -> Result.
```

It is basically a non-empty list of `Result` objects, which can themselves hold non-empty lists (`NestedResult` and `NestedListResult`).

My problem is with the case of `NestedListResult` because the induction principle generated using `Schema` doesn't check for every element in the list of `ResponseObject`. It states the following:

```
Scheme ResponseObject_ind := Induction for ResponseObject Sort Prop
    with Result_ind := Induction for Result Sort Prop.

Check ResponseObject_ind.
ResponseObject_ind
     : forall (P : ResponseObject -> Prop) (P0 : Result -> Prop),
       (forall r : Result, P0 r -> P (SingleResponse r)) ->
       (forall r : Result, P0 r -> forall r0 : ResponseObject, P r0 -> P (MultipleResponses r r0)) ->
       P0 Empty ->
       (forall s : Name, P0 (Null s)) ->
       (forall (s : Name) (s0 : Vals), P0 (SingleResult s s0)) ->
       (forall (s : Name) (l : seq Vals), P0 (ListResult s l)) ->
       (forall (s : Name) (r : ResponseObject), P r -> P0 (NestedResult s r)) ->
       (forall (s : Name) (l : seq ResponseObject), P0  (NestedListResult s l)) -> forall r : ResponseObject, P r
```

I tried following the example from [SSReflect GenTree](http://math-comp.github.io/math-comp/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.choice.html#GenTree.tree_ind) (where it basically folds over the list and checks that each element satisfies the predicate) but I get a syntax error when trying to define it (I guess it's a syntax error?) and I am not sure how to fix it. My guess is that using `fix` and `with` is not correct and I should write it some other way?

My attempt is this:

```
Definition ResponseObject_ind P Ps IH_SingleResponse IH_MultipleResponses IH_Empty IH_Null IH_SingleResult IH_ListResult IH_NestedResult IH_NestedListResult :=
    fix loop (r : ResponseObject) : P r : Prop :=
       match r with
       | SingleResponse r' => IH_SingleResponse r' (Result_ind r')
       | MultipleResponses r' rs => IH_MultipleResponses r' (Result_ind r') rs (loop rs)
       end
      with Result_ind (r : Result) : Ps r : Prop :=
       match r with
       | Empty => IH_Empty
       | Null l => IH_Null l
       | SingleResult l v => IH_SingleResult l v
       | ListResult l vals => IH_ListResult l vals
       | NestedResult l r' => IH_NestedResult l r' (Result_ind r')
       | NestedListResult l rs =>
         let fix iter_conj rs : foldr (fun r => and (P r)) True rs :=
             if rs is r :: rs' then conj (loop r) (iter_conj rs') else Logic.I
         in
         IH_NestedListResult l rs (iter_conj rs)
       end.
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

PS. Actually, maybe some other approach is better than using mutually recursive types... Before I was using `ResponseObject` as another constructor for the `Result` type and checking that it forms a "proper" list (no nested `ResponseObject`s forming a weird tree thing). This option above seems more elegant but maybe it's not too handy.

Comment: Can you make your example self contained:  include also the few lines that load the part of the math-components library on which you rely.  It will make it is easier to build a solution to your problem.

Comment: where does `ordType` come from?

Comment: `ordType` comes from Arthur's extructures library (https://github.com/arthuraa/extructures). Yeah! I forgot to include the load section :)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution does not respect syntax and typing constraints.  One way to fix these constraints leads to the following code:

```
Definition ResponseObject_ind' (P : ResponseObject -> Prop) 
 (Ps : Result -> Prop) IH_SingleResponse IH_MultipleResponses IH_Empty IH_Null
IH_SingleResult IH_ListResult
(IH_NestedResult : forall (s : Name) (r : ResponseObject),
   P r -> Ps (NestedResult s r))
IH_NestedListResult :=
fix loop (r : ResponseObject) : P r : Prop :=
   match r with
   | SingleResponse r' => IH_SingleResponse r' (Result_ind r')
   | MultipleResponses r' rs => IH_MultipleResponses r' (Result_ind r') rs (loop rs)
   end
  with Result_ind (r : Result) : Ps r : Prop :=
   match r with
   | Empty => IH_Empty
   | Null l => IH_Null l
   | SingleResult l v => IH_SingleResult l v
   | ListResult l vals => IH_ListResult l vals
   | NestedResult l r' => IH_NestedResult l r' (loop r')
   | NestedListResult l rs =>
     let fix iter_conj rs : foldr (fun r => and (P r)) True rs :=
         if rs is r :: rs' then conj (loop r) (iter_conj rs') else Logic.I
     in
     IH_NestedListResult l rs (iter_conj rs)
   end
 for loop.
```

I don't like your `iter_conj` solution.

In my opinion, you are in fact producing a bunch of inductive types that contains three inductive types:  `ResponseObject`, `Result`, and `seq ResponseObject`.  So instead of having your induction principle taking two predicates `P` and `Ps`, you should have three predicates: `P` for type `ResponseObject`, `Ps` for `Result`, and `Pl` for `seq ResponseObject`.  Here is my solution following these lines:

```
Definition RO_ind := fun
  P P0 P1 
  (f : forall r : Result, P0 r -> P (SingleResponse r))
  (f0 : forall r : Result,
        P0 r ->
        forall r0 : ResponseObject, P r0 -> P (MultipleResponses r r0))
  (f1 : P0 Empty) (f2 : forall n : Name, P0 (Null n))
  (f3 : forall (n : Name) (v : Vals), P0 (SingleResult n v))
  (f4 : forall (n : Name) (l : seq Vals), P0 (ListResult n l))
  (f5 : forall (n : Name) (r : ResponseObject), P r -> P0 (NestedResult n r))
  (f6 : forall (n : Name) (l : seq ResponseObject),
          P1 l -> P0 (NestedListResult n l))
  (f7 : P1 [::])
  (f8 : forall (ro : ResponseObject),  P ro ->
       forall (l : seq ResponseObject),
       P1 l -> (P1 (ro :: l))) (ro : ResponseObject) =>
fix F (r : ResponseObject) : P r :=
  match r as r0 return (P r0) with
  | SingleResponse r0 => f r0 (F0 r0)
  | MultipleResponses r0 r1 => f0 r0 (F0 r0) r1 (F r1)
  end
with F0 (r : Result) : P0 r :=
  match r as r0 return (P0 r0) with
  | Empty => f1
  | Null n => f2 n
  | SingleResult n v => f3 n v
  | ListResult n l => f4 n l
  | NestedResult n r0 => f5 n r0 (F r0)
  | NestedListResult n l => f6 n l
    ((fix F1 l' : P1 l' :=
       match l' with
       | [::] => f7
       | ro :: l' => f8 ro (F ro) l' (F1 l')
       end) l)
  end
for F0.
```

This solution was produced by calling the `Scheme` command and then editing the header (to add `P1` and `f7` and `f8` for sequences) and finally editing the case of the `NestedListResult` construct.

Comment: Ohhh... I see, I forgot the  `for F` at the end (well.. also other small errors).
Mmhh that looks better than using `iter_conj`, what are the main reasons you don't like that solution? Does it look harder to work with? or is it a cleaner/more elegant solution? (It does to me but I don't really know why :p)

Comment: Also, what do you mean when you say that `This solution was produced by calling the Scheme command and then editing the header` ? Can you edit the definition after calling `Scheme` or you meant that this solution was based on what `Scheme` generates in the "simple" case? Thank you very much :) !

Comment: I called the `Scheme` command that you proposed and then `Print` on the name of the generated induction principle.  Then I copy-pasted in my definition and edited it to add the `fix` construct.

Comment: I believe that your solution, called `ResponseObject_ind'` in my answer, is not able of proving everything that the other induction principle can.  But I don't have an example in mind just now.